# Select and get special svg element by PHP script

Tags: php, parsing, svg, domdocument, domxpath

Need to get and modify first `polygon` inside the group `g` with special (dynamic) `id` inside SVG file by php script.
Couldn't find this element, using DOMDocument() and DOMXPath. Please, help

PHP:

```
$svg = file_get_contents($svgPath);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($svg);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('svg','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
**$curPolygon = $xpath -> query("//svg:g[@id='fl_1']/polygon[0]");**
if ($curPolygon ) {
  $curPolygon [0]->setAttribute('fill', '#ae8f72');
}
$svg = $doc->saveXML($doc);
echo $svg;
```

SVG:

```
<svg>
...
<g id="Flats">

    ...

    <g id="fl_1">
        <polygon fill="none" points="0,0 436.5,0 436.5,197.7 257,197.7 257,267.1 196.9,267.1 196.9,293.9 0,293.9"/>
        <g> <rect x="209.9" y="84.8" fill="#AE8E72" width="56.3" height="22.1"/> </g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 214.1091 101.5043)"><tspan x="0" y="0">4</tspan></text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 235.5047 101.5042)">132,0</text>
    </g>

    <g id="fl_2">
        <polygon fill="none" points="404.5,388.7 404.5,390 251.7,390 251.7,192.3 436.5,192.3 436.5,388.7"/>
        <g> <rect x="327.7" y="278.4" fill="#AE8E72" width="56.3" height="22.1"/> </g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 331.8962 295.0608)"><tspan x="0" y="0">1</tspan></text>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 354.9925 295.0607)">40,7</text>
    </g>

    ...
</g>
...
</svg>
```

Result of `var_dump($q)` is `object(DOMNodeList)#6 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things from your code.  The first is that you don't seem to load the document...

```
$doc->loadXML($svg);
```

the second part is the XPath expression.  I think if you have the namespace `svg` as the default namespace, then you would need to apply this to both parts of the XPath expression.  Also XPath arrays start at 1, so the expression should be

```
$curPolygon = $xpath -> query("//svg:g[@id='fl_1']/svg:polygon[1]");
```

Comment: You are a magician! Forgot paste loadXML in task but the solution - query string. Thanks a lot. I would like to be able to.